Exception Handling Sample in Spring Integration
I am looking for an good error handling example for spring integration.  All I really want to do is a call a method, when this flow fails.  The idea is the called method will send out an error email.
   @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sampleHasErrorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource())
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle("sampleBean", "methodThatThrowsException")
                                .channel(filesProcessedChannel())))
               
                 .get();
    }

I just want to "catch" the exception thrown in methodThatThrowsException().  Can someone produce a quick sample?

Not clear why do you use that publishSubscribeChannel if you just do a single handle() over there. Something like this:
  return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource())
                   .handle("sampleBean", "methodThatThrowsException")
                   .channel(filesProcessedChannel())
                   .get();

Does exactly the same.
So, if we are agree about this configuration, you can look into an errorChannel() option of the endpoint configurer for that from(fileReadingMessageSource()):
IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource(), e -> e.errorChannel()).

Since it is a channel, you simply can implement another flow with a handle(Mail.outboundAdapter()) to produce an email as you requested.
The point is that Spring Integration just re-throws exception as it is to the call. In case of Source Polling Channel Adapter it is a scheduled task, which has a try..catch to sent an exception to the mentioned errorChannel.
Another way is to use ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice exactly on the endpoint for the .handle("sampleBean", "methodThatThrowsException"), but that is a bit complicated.
Note: the IntegrationFlows was deprecated and removed long time ago. So, you probably use Spring Integration version which is out of support: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#support
See more info about error handling in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/error-handling.html

What class is e in you sample?

This IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource(), e -> e.errorChannel()) doesn't compile for me.

The method errorChannel() is undefined for the type SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec

Yeah... Sorry, that one is a part of poller(): e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000).errorChannel())

So is that just the errorChannel for the file reader, or does it cover the handler, also?

It covers that part of the flow which is executed on the thread where the message is produced by file reader.

Well, in my example, I was trying to catch the exception in methodThatThrowsException.  So your answer wouldn't cover that?

It will, because that method is called exactly in the thread we are talking about. So, the exception thrown from there is going to try..catch in the ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor which will call MessagePublishingErrorHandler, and that one will send an ErrorMessage to the provided errorChannel.
